# Change the Default view in Case?

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

I have two pages which need to override the default view of the Case as per the Case Page Layout.I am having two layouts A and B.This layouts is having two Record types.

Comment: can u please add more details to ur question. its not clear what problem u r facing or what are you trying to resolve..

Comment: I am having two records type i:e Test1 and Test2 which is having two different page layout A & B. Now what I want to display this with the help of Standard View on Case object. What I have done is assign the custom page to Case view to display details.But I want to View 2 visual force pages as per the records  type.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand right, u have 2 record types and 2 vf pages which you want to use in place of standard page layouts. if this is the case, then can u tell me how are you providing the user an option to select a record type?

Answer (score 0):

Once you override the view you cannot specify different pages for each record type. I would suggest you put the logic in one VF page to redirect to the page you want for each record type, or reduce to a single VF page and selectively show parts of the page. It depends how different the two VF pages are.